# variadic templates

Tags: c++

Имеется шаблонная функция, принимающая строки

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(const std::string& function, const Args&... args)
{
    PGresult* exec_result = nullptr;
    size_t param_count = sizeof...(args);
    const char** param_pack = new const char*[param_count];

    std::vector<std::string> argsv = {args ...};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < argsv.size(); ++i)
    {
        param_pack[i] = argsv[i].c_str();
    }
...
```

Как сформировать массив указателей на содержимое строк без вектора?

UPD1:
Я извиняюсь за неточно поставленный вопрос.

Возможно ли получить массив указателей на содержимое строк не создавая промежуточных контейнеров (vector/array...), а итерируясь напрямую по args

Comment: `std::array<std::string, sizeof...(args)> argsv{args ...};`

Comment: @VTT, в этом случае будет создан std::array, можно ли вообще избежать создания контенеров и напрямую пройтись по args?

Comment: Определитесь, вам надо создавать массив или пройтись по аргс не создавая массив?

Comment: @VTT, мне надо получить массив указателей на содержимое строк, переданных в args, который param_pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

см. [Brace-enclosed initializers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Brace-enclosed_initializers) на cppreference.

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(const std::string& function, const Args&... args)
{
    ...
    const char* param_pack[] = { (args.c_str())... };
    ...
}
```

Ссылка на [пример](https://onlinegdb.com/B1A0uVbbm)

Comment: то что надо, спасибо!